# Using JS prepend for a div, rather than hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some existing code with a select box, where I'm looking at the option value and matching it to the value of a hidden input for divs within a foreach loop. I got it working the way I want (where, depending on the selection, if the value of the hidden input is '0' it would hide that div). Again, the show/hide works perfectly.

However, I now need to get it working so that if the value is '1' it would prepend those affected divs or show them first. I've never used prepend or append before and I can't get this working for some reason. I tried using the value '0' with append but it just hid everything. I think prepend would be better.

Here's the previous Working 'hide' javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('#filterText').on('change', function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  console.log(currentVal)

  $(".group-container").show();
  if (currentVal == 'popularity') {
  $('.group-container input[name="topseller"]').each(function (index, value){
  if($(this).val() == "0"){
        $(this).parent('.group-container').hide();
        //console.log(currentVal)
    }
    });
  } else if (currentVal == 'recently_ordered') {
    $('.group-container input[name="reorder"]').each(function (index, value){

        if($(this).val() == "0"){
                $(this).parent('.group-container').hide();
                // console.log(currentVal)
            }
      });
  }
});
});

</script>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div>
   <span style="color:#fff;"><strong>Sort by:</strong></span>
        <select id="filterText" class="uk-text-muted" style="margin-top:10px; width:33%; height:30px; font-size: 16px;" >
        <option id="allitems" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" selected data-default value="" selected data-default>All Items</option>
                                      file
        <option id="recent" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="recently_ordered">Recently Ordered </option>
       </select>
    </div>

@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
<div class="group-container">
        <!-- <input type='hidden' name='search' value='{{ x.search }}' > -->
        <input type="hidden" name="topseller" value="{{$pgroup->topseller}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="reorder" value="{{$pgroup->reorder}}"/>

     //rest of the content here
```

And the new JS I'm attempting, but has no action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('#filterText').on('change', function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  console.log(currentVal)

  $(".group-container").show();

  if (currentVal == 'recently_ordered') {
    $('.group-container input[name="reorder"]').each(function (index, value)
{

        if($(this).val() == "1"){
                $(this).prepend('.group-container')            
            }
      });
  }
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $(this).prepend('.group-container')

This piece of code is going to just prepend the text ".group-container" within the selected element.  So you would get

```
 <input ....>.group-container</input>
```

If you instead did this:

```
$(this).prepend('<div class="group-container">);
```

You would get it added to the beginning of your existing element:

```
<input....><div class="group-container"></div></input>
```

I think what you want is "wrap":

```
$(this).wrap('<div class="group-container">');
```

Which should yield

```
<div class="group-container"><input.../></div>
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: I tried this but there is no action, nor is there a console error. I'm not sure if that's exactly the method I'm looking for though. See, if the dropdown value is ```recently_ordered``` and the value of my hidden input for any .group-container div is 1, I just want the page to shuffle/filter and show those affected divs first on the page